# How to always select the last file in a list?

Tags: python, function, file, loops

Long story short, I am using Python to plot many files on the same grid. I won't post the whole program, as it would be unhelpful and unnecessarily long. This is what I need help with

To summarize, how to I get `ifl == 1` to say something that in pythonic language would equal `ifl == last file in directory`? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
if ifl == len(file_location):
    ....
```

Also, you don't actually need the index, you can do this:

```
file_location = glob.glob('../Data/2016/July/*.nc')

for fl in file_location:
    ...
    if fl == file_location[-1]:
        Plot_Map(temp,lon,lat)
    ...
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks mate

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to get the last item in an iteration, you can do this:

```
for fl in file_location:
    pass
# do stuff with fl
```

After the loop finishes, `fl` will be set to whatever was the last iterated item.

Answer (score 2):

how about, traversing the list backwards?

```
for f in reversed(file_location):
```

so, your condition can stay the same.